# How should I use hook_init()?

Tags: hooks

I'm trying to disable the LabJS module from running on certain pages by following the maintainers instructions at [Compatibility issue with Slickgrid](http://drupal.org/node/1238402).

This is what I have, so far. I tried putting it directly in the page and my themes template.php with the theme's name appended to the function name, but neither work.

```
/**
 * Disable LabJS on certain pages
 */
function versatile_hook_init() {    
  if (current_path() == "private/members/search") {
    define('LABJS_DISABLE', TRUE);
  }
}
```

Can you help pointing me in the right direction?

Comment: Try `versatile_init()` instead of `versatile_hook_init()`. :-) Also, remember [hook_init()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_init/6) doesn't get called on cached pages.

Comment: And if you need to check page path, try hook_boot. The modules aren't loaded in hook_boot yet, beware.

Answer (score 7):

`hook_init()` must be implemented in a custom module. In your example, the function `mymodule_init()` would go into a file named mymodule.module in a custom module named *mymodule*. You would also supply a simple mymodule.info file and put both files in the sites/sitename/modules/mymodule directory.

The custom module must be enabled like any other. Also, when creating a hook implementation, it is usually necessary to clear the cache for Drupal to recognize it. Finally, note that *mymodule* needs to be a unique name different from other modules or themes.

As a minor usage point, [current_path()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--path.inc/function/current_path/7) returns the current URL which may not be the current alias (e.g., node/5). Using [drupal_get_path_alias()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--path.inc/function/drupal_get_path_alias/7) is recommended to always return a friendly alias.

Comment: `mymodule_init()` instead of `mymodule_hook_init()`. ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'll give it a try after I've had some sleep. Good to know about the page caching. Also the page URL's for this page are coming from a Panel, but I assume drupal_get_path_alias() will still work.

Comment: This is what I've got so far, but it's not working

[labjs_disabler.info](http://pastebin.com/CzvwqyXr) and [labjs_disabler.module](http://pastebin.com/pRDuKmpt)

Comment: I forgot a "/" in the labjs_disabler.module, here is the corrected one [labjs_disabler.module](http://pastebin.com/hrLT0gzS)

Comment: The '/' is not needed. Your problem is the name of your hook function. You have labjs_disabler_hook_init, and it should be labjs_disabler_init. 'hook' is a placeholder for the module name.