# Hook_init() and Hook_exit not triggering in template.php

Tags: 7, theming

I have implemented hook_init and hook_exit in template.php

```
<?php 
/* Alter variables */
function mytheme_exit(){
  var_dump("template Hook exit called");
}

/* Alter variables*/
function mytheme_init(){
  var_dump("template Hook init called");
}
```

When I cleared cache, loaded the page, it didnt print anything
I would really appreciate any help from you guys since when I implemented the hook_init and hook_exit in a custom module , it did work. Does these hook not work in template.php??

Comment: Hello, please check this [answer](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/9076/790).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately it's as you suspect - those hooks aren't invoked for themes.

Themes can implement `hook_theme()`, a variety of process/preprocess hooks, and [`alter hooks`](http://drupal.org/node/254940#theme_alter) (there may be others but I can't find a reference right now).

For `hook_init()`, `hook_exit()`, and most other non-alter hooks you'll need to implement them in a custom module.